# Commerce / Rules Adding an additional product (or extra fee) for every 10 products of a certain SKU

Tags: commerce, rules

My company is trying to implement a complex pricing scheme for drupal commerce that is as follows:

For every 10 products of type A you automatically purchase product B (or the total price is increased by $10)

So for 1-10 products of type A in the cart, the total cost should be the cost of product A * the quantity, plus the price of 1 product B ($10)

And for 11-20 products of type A in the cart it should be the the cost of product A * the quantity, plus the price of 2 product B ($20)

Is there any way to implement this with rules or is there any plugin that would accommodate this kind of price scheme? I've tried looking for a significant amount of time already.

The rationale behind this is that a case is required for the product, and the case fits 10 of the products, so you need exactly one for every 10 products.

Comment: I think I wasn't fully registered when I posted. not sure if anyone saw this...